# Why does calling std::move on a const object call the copy constructor when passed to another object?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Why does calling std::move on a `const` object call the copy constructor when passed to another object?  Specifically, the code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo && x) { std::cout << "Move" << std::endl; }
    Foo(Foo const & x) = delete;
};

int main() {
    Foo const x; 
    Foo y(std::move(x)); 
}
```

fails to compile with the message:

```
g++ -std=c++14 test07.cpp -o test07
test07.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test07.cpp:10:36: error: use of deleted function 'Foo::Foo(const Foo&)'
     Foo const x; Foo y(std::move(x)); 
                                    ^
test07.cpp:6:5: note: declared here
     Foo(Foo const & x) = delete;
     ^
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Certainly, I expect it to fail because we can't move a `const` value.  At the same time, I don't understand the route that the code takes before it tries to call the copy constructor.  Meaning, I know that `std::move` converts the element to an x-value, but I don't know how things proceed after that with respect to `const`.

Comment: The `const`ness of the moved object isn't changed, `Foo const&&` cannot bind to `Foo&&` so the compiler tries to access the copy constructor, which fails because it is deleted.

Comment: I'm no expert at move operators, but maybe it's that you can call move on a `const` value, but the result from that can only be accepted into the copy constructor, so the compiler decides to call that.

Comment: "Meaning, I know that std::move converts the element to an x-value"  Actually, it doesn't.  It returns an rvalue reference to the item.

Comment: @BenVoigt, what's the difference?  [basic.lval] _"The result of calling a function whose return type is an rvalue reference to an object type is an xvalue."_

Comment: @Jonathan: The result of the & operator is a pointer, but it doesn't convert its input to a pointer.

Comment: @BenVoigt `std::move` is just a `static_cast` to an xvalue though, so calling it a conversion doesn't seem unreasonable. [expr.static.cast] _"The result of the expression `static_cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression `v` to type `T`."_

Comment: @Jonathan: The input to that conversion is a lvalue reference, not an object. The references are both "bound" to the object.

Comment: @BenVoigt the result of `std::move(v)` is the result of converting the expression `v` (which is an lvalue, and an object, but not an lvalue reference because expressions don't have reference type, [expr]/5) to type `Foo&&` (which is an xvalue) ... I think saying it doesn't convert v to an xvalue is needless pedantry, or just plain wrong.

Comment: @Jonathan: is that eligible to call conversion operators?

Comment: No, the reference is bound directly, so what? That doesn't mean the OP was wrong to say it's a conversion. `std::move` does a static_cast and the result is an xvalue. [expr.static.cast] clearly uses the phrase "conversion ... to type `T`... if `T` is an rvalue reference to object type, the result is an xvalue..." so saying it converts to an xvalue is entirely reasonable. If you think otherwise I suggest you propose a change to the normative wording defining `static_cast`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The type of the result of calling `std::move` with a `T const` argument is `T const&&`, which cannot bind to a `T&&` parameter. The next best match is your copy constructor, which is deleted, hence the error.

Explicitly `delete`ing a function doesn't mean it is not available for overload resolution, but that if it is indeed the most viable candidate selected by overload resolution, then it's a compiler error.

The result makes sense because a move construction is an operation that steals resources from the source object, thus mutating it, so you shouldn't be able to do that to a `const` object simply by calling `std::move`.

Answer (score 13):

The type of `std::move(x)` is `Foo const&&` which can't bind to `Foo&&`. The reasoning is the same as for a `T const&` not being able to bind to a `T&`. You can, however, have a constructor taking a `Foo const&&`. Most likely you won't be able to really *move* the corresponding object's data but, e.g., in your example there no data, i.e., the following code works OK:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo &&) { std::cout << "Move\n"; }
    Foo(Foo const&&) { std::cout << "Move const\n"; }
    Foo(Foo const &) = delete;
};

int main() {
    Foo const x; Foo y(std::move(x)); 
}
```