# Avoiding lambda copies in c++

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda

I need to pass a user defined lambda to MyClass1 through MyClass2. I want to make sure that there is one move and no copies. Is the code below achieving that? Is there a better way to do this (like using implicit move done by compiler)?

Note: I have control over MyClass1 and MyClass2

```
#include <functional>

using MyFunction = std::function<int(int)>;

class MyClass1 {
 public:
   MyClass1(const MyFunction& func): mFunc(std::move(func)) {}

 private:
   MyFunction mFunc;
};

class MyClass2 {
 public:
  MyClass1* getClass1(const MyFunction& func) {
    return new MyClass1(func);
  }
};

int main() {
  MyClass2 cl2;

  const auto& f = [] (int i) { return i; };

  MyClass1* cl1 = cl2.getClass1(f);
}
```

Comment: you cannot move a const reference

Comment: @bolov but it seems to compile fine.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's doing what you want it to. You're copying `func`, change the parameter type to `MyFunction&&`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/27810535/241631

Comment: You can `std::move` something that is `const`, but it usually does *nothing* other than a copy when used.  It is `const`, you aren't allowed to strip its guts out, and `std::move` just marks something as "safe to strip the guts out".  Extra moves are cheap: replace `const MyFunction&` with `MyFunction` everywhere you wrote it.  Replace `MyClass1(func)` with `MyClass1(std::move(func))`.

Comment: Do you understand that it does not make sense until you capture something by `&&`?

Comment: And you can't even copy lambda to the `std::fucntion` if is does capture: http://ideone.com/GQ9Nto

Comment: @Lol4t0 `std::function` requires the callable its wrapping to be copy constructible, yours isn't because of that move only type. Lambdas that capture copyable types are copyable, and can be stored in `std::function`

Comment: @Praetorian, that's, like, apparent. Though it makes non-copyable lamdas a bit useless as they could only be passed as temple arguments

Comment: @Lol4t0 That's like not so apparent from the way you worded it. Sounds as if you're saying lambdas that capture cannot be stored in an `std::function`

Comment: @Praetorian I definitly did not mean that

Comment: @Lol4t0 And `std::function` will capture by move.  So long as the contents are copyable, it is fine: the copy won't be done (the code to do the copy will be compiled).  non-copyable lambdas can be used in a number of contexts: they can be passed to `std::async` or stored in a `std::packaged_task` (which is non-movable) or a few other similar cases.  Or you can write your own 20-line move-only `std::function` (if you want Small Function Optimization, it does take more than 20 lines).

Comment: @Yakk If I replace MyFunction& with MyFunction, won't there be a copy of 'f' when I call cl2.getClass1(f) ?

Comment: @vikky.rk get rid of the `const&` on `f`, and `move` it in anyhow.  Your code (as written above) already copies `f`, as `f` is *not* a `std::function`, it is a lambda.  Lambdas are not `std::function`s, and `std::function`s are not lambdas.  `move`ing it into the `std::function` taking thing will eliminate that copy (and replace it with a move) in both your `std::function<?> const&` case, and my `std::function<?>` case.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can change `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` you can take the function by rvalue reference and then `move` it along

```
#include <functional>

using MyFunction = std::function<int(int)>;

class MyClass1 {
 public:
   MyClass1(MyFunction&& func): mFunc(std::move(func)) {}

 private:
   MyFunction mFunc;
};

class MyClass2 {
 public:
  MyClass1* getClass1(MyFunction&& func) {
    return new MyClass1(std::move(func));
  }
};

int main() {
  MyClass2 cl2;
  const auto& f = [] (int i) { return i; };

  MyClass1* cl1 = cl2.getClass1(f);
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9b63efcdcbe268d)</kbd>

Comment: 'f' looks like an lvalue. How will it work with rvalue reference?