# std::move() with priority_queue.top()

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, move

I am new to smart pointers. Recently I started working on some parallel simulations and I thought `shared_ptr` will help prevent memory leaks. I heard that incrementing the number of instances can cause non-negligible extra time overhead, so I hope to avoid doing that.

In my code I was using a priority_queue to manage the events in the simulation. To make sure I understood what happens with shared_ptr in these containers I did some tests:

```
std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<Base>> queue;
queue.push(std::make_shared<Derived>());
std::shared_ptr<Base> p = queue.top();
//std::shared_ptr<Base> p = std::move(queue.top());

std::cout << "Created a shared Derived (as a pointer to Base)\n"
          << "  p.get() = " << p.get()
          << ", p.use_count() = " << p.use_count() << '\n';
```

Using the above two different ways to get the pointer from the `priority_queue`, I was expecting the second way to return 1 in `use_count()`. However I saw a value of 2, whether or not I used `std::move()` to get the top pointer in the queue. I compiled with `g++ -std=c++0x [FileName]`

Can someone point out where I was doing wrong? Do both the methods above indicate I will still have extra time over head?

Comment: Probably has something to do with the fact that `top` `return`s a `const&`.  Also, you probably don't want to `move` the result of `top` since `queue` will still expect it to be valid.

Comment: Did you bother measuring whether incrementing the `shared_ptr` reference count is really a bottleneck for you before jumping through hoops to avoid it?

Comment: Did you consider using `std::unique_ptr`? Who shares the objects in the queue?

Comment: To be honest I do not think this will increse the total running time by a lot. However I am still curious.

Comment: Ah, nm, I just seen you can't really put `unique_ptr` in a `priority_queue`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`priority_queue::top`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/top) returns a `const&` to the top element.

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> p = queue.top();
```

The line above creates a new `shared_ptr` which now shares ownership of the top element with the `shared_ptr` that's in the `priority_queue`, so `use_count` is 2.

`std::move` doesn't affect the result because [moving a `const` object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27810535/241631) will call the `shared_ptr` copy constructor, same as the line above.

To keep `use_count` at 1, use

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> const& p = queue.top();
```

Comment: Doesn't taking a reference defeat the point of the smart pointer somewhat? It can't be used in a different scope and if `queue.top()` is changed, it becomes dangling. Is it really any more useful than using `queue.top()` directly?

Comment: @Galik Depends on what you're doing with the reference. Maybe the OP wants to do some stuff with the top element, then `p` is a lot less typing compared to `queue.top()`. Of course you can store the reference, pop the queue and have yourself a dangling reference, but in no way does taking a reference to a `shared_ptr` mean you always end up in that situation. Basically, unless you want a second object that shares ownership, use a reference.

Comment: I suppose I just assumed the OP wants to take it out to send it somewhere else after he `pop()` the top of the queue. But we don't really know what happens to it.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you use_count of 1.

```
const std::shared_ptr<Base>& p = queue.top();
```

And, this should give you use_count of 2.

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> p = queue.top();
```

_

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:

    Base() {}

    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "Base" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived
:
    public Base
{
    public:
    Derived() {}

    void print()
    {
        cout << "Derived" << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{

  std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<Base>> queue;
  queue.push(std::make_shared<Derived>());
  const std::shared_ptr<Base>& p = queue.top();
  //std::shared_ptr<Base> p = std::move(queue.top());

  std::cout << "Created a shared Derived (as a pointer to Base)\n"
            << "  p.get() = " << p.get()
                      << ", p.use_count() = " << p.use_count() << '\n';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`queue.top()` returns `const_reference`, const can not be moved. Const returned since elements in a priority queue are not allowed to be modified, it can break an order in a priority queue.

Answer (score 0):

Move does not delete the object pointed to. It leaves it in some "valid but unspecified state." (Their words, not mine.) Or at least it will if Base and Derived play by the rules. If rather than Derived, you had used std::strings, they would probably be left as empty strings, but it would be legal for the implementation to leave them as "Surprise! Moved out.".

Comment: There's no move happening in the example above

Comment: It's commented out.

Comment: No, I mean even if you uncomment that, there's no move construction because `top` returns a `const&`