# unique_ptr, you're referencing a deleted function

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

I'm attempting to move a `unique_ptr` to the `WriteAsync` method. This works as expected. The issue I'm having is now moving ownership of the unique pointer into the `strand.post` lambda, and then, moving it again, into `QueueMessage`.
`QueueMessage` takes a `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<char>>`.

The easy way for me in this case would be to just use a `shared_ptr`. I'm wondering if there is a way to make this work without the use of a `shared_ptr`.

```
// Caller
static void DoWork( char const* p, int len  )
{
     client.WriteAsync( std::make_unique<std::vector<char>>( p, p + len ) );
}

// Callee
void TcpClient::WriteAsync( std::unique_ptr<std::vector<char>> buffer )
{
    _strand.post( [ this, buffer = std::move( buffer ) ]( ) 
    { 
        // Error on this line.
        QueueMessage( std::move( buffer ) ); 
    } );
}


void TcpClient::QueueMessage( std::unique_ptr<std::vector<char>> buffer )
{
     // Do stuff
}
```

The error I'm seeing is:

> you're referencing a deleted function

Comment: You are having _"...issues..."_: what are they, error messages etc?

Comment: Why are you using a `unique_ptr` of `vector`? That seems at the very least very strange, there is pretty much never any need to dynamically allocate a `std::vector`

Comment: `QueueMessage` is a method, and I don't like `move` methods.

Comment: What error message are you getting, and what is the declaration of `QueueMessage`?

Comment: Agree with @UnholySheep , but in the interests of better exploring the question as asked, can we get a [mcve]? Odds are good that producing the MCVE will result in a face-palm and fixing it yourself, but the game is answering questions and a win is a win.

Comment: I added the `QueueMessage` declaration. Nothing fancy. @UnholySheep I suppose I should just pass the vector by value and let the `vectors` move semantics do the work.

Comment: @RichardCritten The error is posted in the subject.

Comment: @WBuck A `std::vector` has the *equivalent* of a *unique_ptr* inside itself pointing to its data so having a *unique_ptr* to a `std::vector` is somewhat redundant. You can `std::move` a `std::vector` just like you do with the *unique_ptr*.

Comment: @WBuck You should always copy paste the error message in the body of the question. And, as always, post a [mcve].

Comment: Why use `vector<char>` at all and not `std::string`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not actually dealing with strings, I just used that in this example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lambda's function call operator is a `const` member function. So `std::move(buffer)` will return `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<char>>> const&&`, which matches the deleted `unique_ptr` copy constructor [instead of its move constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27810604/241631), hence the error.

To fix the error, make your lambda [`mutable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), this will make `operator()()` non-`const`, allowing you to move construct `buffer`

```
[ buffer = std::move( buffer ) ] ( ) mutable 
//                                   ^^^^^^^
{
   QueueMessage( std::move( buffer ) );
}
```