# Why const reference is called and not rvalue reference and how std::move works?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, lvalue-to-rvalue, pass-by-const-reference, pass-by-rvalue-reference

```
#include <iostream>

void bar(std::string& s) { std::cout << "ref" << std::endl;}
void bar(const std::string& s) { std::cout << "const ref" << std::endl;}
void bar(std::string&& s) { std::cout << "rvalue ref" << std::endl;}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const std::string text{"text"};
  bar(text); 
  bar(std::string{"text"});
  bar("text"); 

  std::string text1{"text"};
  bar(text1);

 bar(std::move(text)); 

  return 0;
}
```

I expected rvalue ref to be printed for the last function call, not const ref. Why is const ref printed instead of rvalue ref? I thought that std::move takes the text variable and adds && to it and turns it into an rvalue ref, but it obviously doesn't work that way. Since rvalue can be bound to both rvalue ref and const ref, which one has priority? Can someone help me?

Comment: `text` is const. It cannot be moved.

Comment: see what happens when you add a const rvalue ref overload (which doesnt make much sense usually, only for illustration here) https://godbolt.org/z/E9ocdnG9q

Comment: `std::move` returns `const std::string &&` here. It can't bind to `std::string &&` because that would lose const, so it falls back to `const std::string &`.

Comment: Is it a typo and you meant to write `bar(std::move(text1));`?

Comment: The answer in this dupe: [Why can we use `std::move` on a `const` object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28595207/12002570). Here is another dupe: [Why does calling std::move on a const object call the copy constructor when passed to another object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810535/why-does-calling-stdmove-on-a-const-object-call-the-copy-constructor-when-pass)

Answer (score 2):

Casting a const value as a *rvalue* reference does not magically discard the const-qualifier. So it's essentially `const std::string&&`. The closest match for that type in the functions you provided is `const std::string&`.